# Tracking alias is sometimes bypassed in tracking analysis - What is causing this?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email-tracking

I am kinda curious how tracking aliases can be bypassed, by some of our email recipients. I double checked it on the same e-mail and clicked any possible link. I cannot reproduce the links in tracking that are shown without a tracking alias(yellow marker). I also tried different clients.

- Is this something which is just caused by some e-mail clients?
- Is this
  something that can be related to some kind of AdBlocking?
- Is this
  something that firewalls can cause?

[image]

Sidenote: Web Analytic Connector (WAC) is enabled.

Comment: Do you use impression regions around them?

Comment: Well most of the links are inside dynamic content blocks which itself start and end impression regions around them. So my answer would be yes. But i do not start them outside of dynamic content blocks.

Comment: There is a 'known issue' with aliasing inside of impression regions that will cause the alias to be removed when used inside of an impression region. Support gives very little info on this other than it is known and that it happens. Wish I had more info or better news to share.

Comment: @JohannesSchapdick Did you by any chance get to the root cause and possible solutions of this? I'm currently facing this issue even with messages that don't use impression regions and can't reproduce it. Thank you!